# Restricting inner query with outer query atttribute

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I currently have a large SQL query (not mine) which I need to modify. I have a transaction and valuation table. The transaction has a one-to-many relationship with valuations. The two tables are being joined via a foreign key.

I've been asked to prevent any transactions (along with their subsequent valuations) from being returned if no valuations for a transaction exist past a certain date. The way I thought I would achieve this would be to use an inner query, but I need to make the inner query aware of the outer query and the transaction. So something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE T 
INNER JOIN VALUATION_TABLE V WHERE T.VAL_FK = V.ID 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V WHERE V.DATE > <GIVEN DATE>) > 1
```

Obviously the above wouldn't work as the inner query is separate and I can't reference the outer query V reference from the inner. How would I go about doing this, or is there a simpler way?

This would just be the case of setting the WHERE V.DATE >  in the outer query as I want to prevent any valuation for a given transaction if ANY of them exceed a specified date, not just the ones that do.

Many thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may looking for this

```
SELECT * 
FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE T 
INNER JOIN VALUATION_TABLE V1 ON T.VAL_FK = V1.ID 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM VALUATION_TABLE V2 
       WHERE V2.ID = V1.ID AND V2.DATE > <GIVEN DATE>) > 1
```

Comment: I think you (OP) want `> 0`. And if so you can use `exists` to possibly make it faster.

Comment: Reading the question again it also appears you may want the reverse condition: `= 0` or `not exists`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  TRANSACTION_TABLE T 
      INNER JOIN VALUATION_TABLE V1 ON T.VAL_FK = V.ID 
WHERE V.ID IN ( SELECT ID 
                FROM   VALUATION_TABLE
                WHERE  DATE > <GIVEN DATE>
              )
```

If execution time is important, you may want to test the various solutions on your actual data and see which works best in your situation.